# When connecting with GNU Screen (patched version) RPi reprompts for password in kind of loop

Tags: serial, serial-console

I have a raspberry pi (running raspian) and want to connect to it with the Console Cable. I succeeded - and I tried twice, because it had worked before, but malfunctioned the second time (this is a follow-up on my previous question) - and after these two times I waited for a few minutes and then, it suddenly didn't work anymore.
Now, when I connect with screen (`sudo screen /dev/cu.PL[some long number] 115200`) I can see the password prompt, but withing a few milliseconds a new one appears, in some kind of loop.

A screen shot illustrates it best, I think:

[image]

It doesn't stop echoing these two lines, and it happens far two quick to even read it without making a screenshot, let alone typing a username and password.